# Thread in DLL has not be closed correctly. What can I do?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll

I have a DLL from one of my vendors that has an issue closing down its internal threads and creates a ThreadAbortException whenever I call their Close/Dispose method. The Close/Dispose call, however, returns just fine, so I suspect the Exception is caught but not handled in the DLL.

Short of reporting the error and get it fixed by the vendor, can I do anything to close down the thread myself? I have tried to see if I can identify the thread using the following code:

```
ProcessThreadCollection threads = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads;

for (int i = 0; i < threads.Count; i++)
{
   ProcessThread pt = threads[i];       
   Debug.WriteLine($"{i+1}: ID: {pt.Id}, ");
}
```

But I haven't yet been able to find the exact thread I am looking for. I know where it is located using the Debug Thread view, but I can't find that location through C# code.

Is it at all possible to locate that thread, inside a DLL and then somehow attempt to kill that thread so the application does not hang when closing down?

Comment: killing threads is almost always a terrible idea; it may be a better option to talk to your vendor, show them the problem, and either get advice on how to shutdown cleanly, or a bugfix if it is an unknown problem

Comment: @MarcGravell I am aware that is it not a good idea and know the risks. But in this instance, I am willing to take those risks and they are minimal as all other working tasks are complete.